# What does dorso, ventro, and orbital mean in prefrontal cortext?

Tags: neuroanatomy

The prefrontal cortex has 3 parts:

- Dorso prefrontal cortex
- Ventro prefortal cortex
- Orbital prefrontal cortex

What does dorso, and ventro mean?

I thought orbital means back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [anatomical terms of location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location).

The [orbits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_%28anatomy%29) are the cavities in the skull that hold the eyes. You can easily remember this if you remember that an orbit, in English, is a circular object or path: the Moon orbits the Earth. So

- "orbito-" means "towards the eyes", i.e. on the underside of the prefrontal cortex

In a four footed animal like a dog or horse

- dorsal means towards the back (i.e. where a rider would sit on a horse)
- ventral means towards the belly (underside)

Because human beings no longer walk on all fours, their [neuraxis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuraxis) is bent, with the bend between the brain stem and the diencephalon:

- in the torso and old brain parts, dorsal means towards the back, ventral towards the belly and face
- in the cerebrum and diencephalon, dorsal means towards the top, ventral towards the bottom of the skull

Here is an illustration ("oder" means "or" in German):

[image]

I find English a bit confusing as to what the word "back" denotes. In other languages, like Latin, the words for the spinal side of the torso (*dorsum*, back) and the tail end of the body (*posterior*, back) are distinct. In English, they are the same, and this makes an explanation of these anatomical terms confusing in English.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, the [orbitofrontal cortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbitofrontal_cortex) "gets its name from its position immediately above the orbits in which the eyes are located." **Orbital does not mean "back."**

Continuing from Wikipedia, **[Dorsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorsum_%28anatomy%29) is Latin for "back,"** and, "Dorsal (posterior) means the back or toward the back of the body; behind." Venter is Latin for "belly," and as for "ventral", [Merriam-Webster's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ventral) 1b seems most pertinent: "Being or located near or on the anterior or lower surface of an animal opposite the back."

---

**TL;DR version:**
[image]